# How to replace deprecated ~E sigil with ~H in Phoenix render funciton

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, sigils

### Background

In my quest to learn Phoenix LiveView I found myself using a render function that uses a deprecated sigil:

```
  def render(_assigns) do
    ~E"""
    <menubar>
      <menu label="<%= gettext "File" %>">
          <hr/>
          <item onclick="quit"><%= gettext "Quit" %></item>
      </menu>
      <menu label="<%= gettext "Extra" %>">
          <item onclick="browser"><%= gettext "Open Browser" %></item>
      </menu>
    </menubar>
    """
  end
```

Now, I understand this is a safe for to use `eex` code inside of Elixir. However the compiler says I should replace it with `~H`. So my firs try is the following:

```
  def render(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    <menubar>
      <menu label="{@gettext('File')}">
          <hr/>
          <item onclick="quit"><%= gettext "Quit" %></item>
      </menu>
      <menu label="{@gettext 'Extra'}">
          <item onclick="browser"><%= gettext "Open Browser" %></item>
      </menu>
    </menubar>
    """
  end
```

Which does not work and does not show the text properly in the menu:

[image]

### Quesion

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

The problem in my attempt was the `@` character. I likely miss understood the error message and concluded the `@` had to be part of the variable.

The correct version looks like this:

```
  def render(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    <menubar>
      <menu label={gettext("File")}>
          <hr/>
          <item onclick="quit"><%= gettext "Quit" %></item>
      </menu>
      <menu label={gettext("Extra")}>
          <item onclick="browser"><%= gettext "Open Browser" %></item>
      </menu>
    </menubar>
    """
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `~L` if you are having tough time with sigil H.